# How can I create Data Base on phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, database-design, linux, phpmyadmin, errors

I have a serious problem here. I am not able to create data bases as the option is not to be found on my `phpMyAdmin`, but it only shows 'No Privilege' in red font.

I even tried to create data base directly from terminal using the command `mysql -u akht -p`(akht is my database name) but then it shows

> Error 1044 --->access denied for user___ to database___

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: _but it only shows 'No Privilege' in red font._

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging in to PHPMyAdmin as root?

You should have been asked to give a root password when you installed MySQL. Create a user ("fred") and then give fred privileges to access/manipulate that db - GRANT ALL ON My_database TO fred (or similar (from memory... check the docco).

[EDIT] My thanks to my learned friend @RickJames for providing the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> mysql -u akht -p(akht is my database name) 
>   -u is for "user"; -p (without a space after it) is for "password"; a lone word (no -x before it) is the database name.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'fred'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```